# In Caché ObjectScript, what is the `Aliases' property keyword

Tags: syntax, intersystems-cache, intersystems, mumps, intersystems-ensemble

[Under Intersystems Property Keywords documentation](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20101/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=ROBJ_property_keywords) `Aliases` is not listed as a keyword. However, in studio if I type

`Property Tst As %String [`

the drop-down pops up with Aliases and fills it with

`Property Tst As %String [ Aliases =`

The only way I got it to compile is

`Aliases = { "some value?" } ];`

So, how is `Aliases` used?

UPDATE: I know I did this backwards, found a feature then looked for a problem, but I found a use-case. If you are an ensemble user, the message viewer only displays the message if its "valid"ish xml, i.e. no spaces in the xml tag names. However your object has to have space in the property name,

`Property "Due Date?" As %String;`

you can do the following

`Property "DueDate" As %String [ Aliases = {Due Date} ];`

and still reference the property by the old name `obj."Due Date?"`, allowing the message to show up in the viewer and keeping the old "vernacular'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: it actually does work, but the syntax is

```
Property Name As %String [ Aliases = {name2} ];
```

So, no quotes.

What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Curiosity, Ok so, I was setting ```Aliases = { another property }``` and that wasn't doing anything, I changed it up to ```{ some name that doesn't exist }``` and then I could reference it by both names

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not used at all. Because have no any reference in documentation or in code about it.